# elasticsearch- how to find exact date type values?

Tags: spring, date, elasticsearch

So I'm using elasticsearch with spring framework, and I'm having trouble get hits by exact date value.

Here's my property mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "creationDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Here's the mapping in the java class:

```
@Field(type =   Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Calendar creationDate;
```

The problem is when I try to search for an exact date:

```
GET test/searchableSo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "creationDate": {
        "value": "14-11-2014 05:55:46"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't return anything, only if I use the long equivalent:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "creationDate": {
        "value": "1415987746214"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any insight?

Comment: This sounds like incorrect mapping. In ES can you try running `GET /test/_mapping` to see if the mapping you think exists in ES, is it really there? (meaning the correct format, if any, for your `creation_date`)

Comment: Yeah it gives for the correct field:

"properties": {
               "creationDate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
               }

Comment: When you save a java Calendar field, it will show the long value right? this is the normal behaviour?

Comment: Ok. How do you index your data? Like `14-11-2014 05:55:46` or `1415987746214`?

Comment: i just save the data with java Calendar, i don't add anything specifically besides the mapping you see above.

Comment: I assume the date is parsed according to the format. It will then be stored as some kind of datetime , which is stored as a Long (in Java) representing the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it is safer to use the range filter instead of term/match when dealing with date fields.

Elasticsearch internally stores date type as a long value. 
So I believe passing **1415987746214** while indexing should end up storing the value as is.

Hence ***1415987746214*** is not the same as "**14-11-2014 05:55:46".**  because of the millisecond portion.

Try indexing it without the millisecond portion i.e. "***1415987746000***" 
or you could use the ***numeric_resolution*** setting to be seconds in the  mapping and specify timestamp in seconds since epoch while indexing i.e. 1415987746

Example:

```
 "properties": { "creationDate": { "type": "date", "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ,"numeric_resolution" : "seconds"},..}
```

either  would work for the query :

```
{ "query": { "term": { "creationDate": { "value": "14-11-2014 17:55:46" } } } }
```

remember to use the 24 hour clock.

Comment: Hi! How do you configure this in java annotations? the @Field doesn't seem to have a numeric_resolution property.
Also you said its better to use Range filter, but what if you want exact values? Range filter doesn't have an equal comparator.

Comment: probably numeric_resoluton is not supported in spring elasticsearch, i need to look into it further and get back .For range filter you should use the gte, lt for the range i.e  gte  : 14-11-2014 17:55:46 and lt 14-11-2014 17:55:47 this way if you index a timestamp with "ms" resolution it would still detect documents .

Comment: Yeah the solution here was setting the milliseconds to 0.
 calDateCreation.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);